# javascript: do primitive strings have methods?

Tags: javascript, string, primitive

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JS/Glossary) states:

> primitive, primitive value
>
> A data that is not an object and does
> not have any methods. JavaScript has 5
> primitive datatypes: string, number,
> boolean, null, undefined. With the
> exception of null and undefined, all
> primitives values have object
> equivalents which wrap around the
> primitive values, e.g. a String object
> wraps around a string primitive. All
> primitives are immutable.

So when we call a  `"s".replace` or `"s".anything` is it equivalent to `new String("s").replace` and `new String("s").anything`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, string primitives do not have methods. As with numeric primitives, the JavaScript runtime will promote them to full-blown "String" objects when called upon to do so by constructs like:

```
var space = "hello there".indexOf(" ");
```

In some languages (well, Java in particular, but I think the term is in common use) it's said that the language "boxes" the primitives in their object wrappers when appropriate.  With numbers it's a little more complicated due to the vagaries of the token grammar; you can't just say

```
var foo = 27.toLocaleString();
```

because the "." won't be interpreted the way you'd need it to be; however:

```
var foo = (27).toLocaleString();
```

works fine. With string primitives — and booleans, for that matter — the grammar isn't ambiguous, so for example:

```
var foo = true.toString();
```

will work.

Comment: heys btw is the double dot syntax "standard" ? Like 27..toLocaleString()

Comment: Well it seems to work in Chrome at least ... the issue is that the low-level "token grammar" will hook the first "." onto the number, because of the way floating-point numbers look ("23.223").  But that double-dot trick *should* work, because the tokenizer will stop at the second ".", leaving it to the parser to construct the property reference expression.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer `(27).toLocaleString()` because it's easy to lose track of a little "." stuck in there. But that's just a stylistic opinion and it isn't worth much :-)

Comment: The first dot after a digit is a decimal point. All browsers have always agreed that 12..toLocaleString() is operating on the number.

Comment: @kennebec that makes good sense, thanks; I haven't personally been keeping track over the past dozen years, but it certainly makes sense given the token grammar etc. :-)

Comment: Is this "auto-promotion" of primitive values to wrapped objects explicitly stated in the spec?

Comment: I think the answer to my previous comment is "yes". See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582032/2160440)

Answer (score 8):

The technically correct answer is "no".

The real-world answer is "no, but it will work anyway". That's because when you do something like

```
"s".replace()
```

the interpreter knows that you want to actually operate on the string as if you had created it with

```
var str = new String("s")
```

and therefore acts as if you had done that.